# How to calculate position value (height) when scrolling item on ListView (Xamarin Forms)?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm building a layout like the main page of [AppStore](https://www.apple.com/vn/ios/app-store/)

This app has handled when the user scrolls [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/), [SearchBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.searchbar?view=xamarin-forms) will gradually hide like the following GIF image:

[image: Gif_Image_ListView]

How to calculate position value (height) when scrolling item on `ListView` (`Xamarin Forms`)?

**Example**: When I scroll an apart of an `item` on `ListView`, `Layout` contains `Searchbar` will hide an apart of it (layout contains `SearchBar`),

with **height** (an apart of item is `scrolled` on `ListView`) = **height** (an apart of `SearchBar` is hidden)

Please suggest me an idea and solution!

Comment: You want to detect the value of height you scrolled?

Comment: Yup. On `Listview` of `Xamarin Forms`, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use custom renderer to detect the value of height you scrolled, I wrote a simple example in iOS:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(myListView), typeof(MyListViewRenderer))]
namespace App556.iOS
{
    public class MyListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Control.Delegate = new myDeleagte();
        }

    }

    public class myDeleagte : UITableViewDelegate {

        public override void Scrolled(UIScrollView scrollView)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(scrollView.ContentOffset.X);
            Console.WriteLine(scrollView.ContentOffset.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Handle your event in the `Scrolled` method or use [messaging-center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to handle event in Xamarin.forms.Project.

ListView only has [itemappearing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.itemappearing?view=xamarin-forms) method for you to do something when scrolling, you can have a look at it.

Comment: It works when using `TableView`. I also found a similar solution to your idea.
https://github.com/syncfusion/essential-ui-kit-for-xamarin.forms
Thanks!